# Unhandled exception: FormatException:

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application

My problem is I Work on flutter app with firebase i make all the steps to can use firebase and i had this exception when i run flutterfire configure command

⠼ Fetching available
Firebase projects...

Unhandled exception:

FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)

#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)

#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)

#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)

#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)

#5      runFirebaseCommand (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:95:25)

#6      getProjects (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:114:20)

#7      ConfigCommand._selectFirebaseProject (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:278:24)

#8      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:368:37)

#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)

#10     main (file:///C:/Users/IT/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutterfire_cli-0.2.6/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)

⠦ Fetching available Firebase projects...

Unhandled exception:

FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)

#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)

#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)

#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)

#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)

#5      runFirebaseCommand (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:95:25)

#6      getProjects (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:114:20)

#7      ConfigCommand._selectFirebaseProject (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:278:24)

#8      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:368:37)

#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)

#10     main (file:///C:/Users/IT/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutterfire_cli-0.2.6/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)

Comment: Describe what do you want to achieve and issue that you faced, please

Comment: My problem is I Work on flutter app with firebase i make all the steps to can use firebase and i had this exception when i run flutterfire configure command

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to update the firebase CLI.

Open a terminal and put these commands:

- `curl -sL firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash`
- `firebase login --reauth`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the above did not work for me and after much research and trying various combinations of things I solved it with the following sequence:

- Delete all associated apps from your Firebase project using the Firebase console
- Delete the following files in your Flutter project folder (if they exist)
  `my_project/lib/firebase_options.dart`
  `my_project/ios/firebase_app_id_file.json`
  `my_project/macos/firebase_app_id_file.json`
  `my_project/android/app/google-services.json`
  `my_project/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist`
  `my_project/macos/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist`
- Activate and deactivate the flutterfire_cli with

  `dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli`

  `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`

For good measure also

- Exit Android Studio (and terminate running emulators & processes) and re-open
- Re-authenticate Firebase CLI with: `firebase login --reauth`

Then re-run `flutterfire configure`

It’s not clear to me whether that all the above steps are necessary (I haven't tried all combinations), but this sequence worked while various subsets of the above did not.

PS I'm developing my Flutter & Firebase project on MacOS with Android Studio.

PPS The `flutterfire configure` issue should resolve without deleting the `GoogleService-Info.plist` files for ios/macos. However I had a stale/bad plist file for my ios build which caused my ios Flutter app to crash. Deleting the .plist file and recreating it by rerunning `flutterfire configure' resolved this additional issue. Hence my recommended is to delete it upfront.